# Why the sum of this series (each term is exponential times polynomial) is $o(1)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality

I find an inequality stating that for any fixed constant $c>0$
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \exp(-c2^{2i}n)(1+2^{i+1}n^{-1/2})\to 0$$
as $n\to \infty$.

I checked when $i=0$, the term tends to 0. And my idea is separate the sum as $i=0$ term and sum of $i\ge 1$ term. I think the latter one can be bound by some type of integral but get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can show it by a rough estimate using

$$e^{c2^{2i}n}\geq c2^{2i}n$$

So, your sum can be bounded from above as follows:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1+\frac{2^{i+1}}{\sqrt n}}{e^{c2^{2i}n}}\leq \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{2^{i+1}+2^{i+1}}{c2^{2i}n}=\frac 4{cn}\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}=\frac 8{cn}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Answer (score 0):

For $c>0$ and $n\ge 1$ and $i\ge 0$ we have $$0<\frac {1+2^{i+1}n^{-1/2}}{\exp(c2^{2i}n)}<$$ $$<\frac {2\cdot 2^{i+1}}{(c2^{2i}n)^2/2!}=$$ $$=\frac {8}{2^{3i}}\cdot \frac {1}{c^2n^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $e^{c2^{i}n} >(c2^{i}n)^{2}/2$. Sow that $\sum \frac  1{(c2^{i}n)^{2}/2}$ and $\sum \frac  {2^{i+1}n^{-1/2}}{(c2^{i}n)^{2}/2}$ both tend to $0$.